# Merge overlapping intervals behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I'm attempting to solve the merge overlapping intervals problem and have the working solution below. However there's a piece of logic that im having problems understanding. Namely the part where the currentInterval[1] gets updated with the max between currentInterval[1] and nextInterval[1]. This piece of code also updates the last array in the mergedIntervals array and I don't fully understand how this is happening as i dont see how the currentInterval is linked with the last array in mergedIntervals. Could someone please explain how mergedIntervals is being updated when we set currentInterval[1]?

```js
 const array = [
      [1, 2],
      [4, 7],
      [9, 10],
      [3, 5],
      [6, 8],
    ];

    function mergeOverlappingIntervals(array) {
      let sortedIntervals = array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
      });
    
      let mergedIntervals = [];
      let currentInterval = sortedIntervals[0];
      mergedIntervals.push(currentInterval);
    
      for (let nextInterval of sortedIntervals) {
        if (currentInterval[1] >= nextInterval[0]) {
          currentInterval[1] = Math.max(
            currentInterval[1],
            nextInterval[1],
          );
        } else {
          currentInterval = nextInterval;
          mergedIntervals.push(nextInterval);
        }
      }
    
      return mergedIntervals;
    }

const result = mergeOverlappingIntervals(array);
console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: *I'm attempting to solve the merge overlapping intervals problem...* Please state your problem completely with the desired outcome.

Comment: The problem is already solved, my question deals with understanding a segment of the code as clearly stated in the op.

Comment: How is someone supposed to explain how some piece of a solution works, if they don't know what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is the merge overlapping intervals problem, part a set of exercises and interview problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that one of the insights you could need for understanding this algorithm is the following:

Even when an interval has already been pushed on the result array, it can still be modified.

And this is what happens. `currentInterval` is always an interval that is already pushed on the result array. This happens already before the loop starts.

But then later on, this interval `currentInterval` is possibly *mutated* (when the `if` condition is true). More precisely, it may get *extended*. Such an extension is effective in the result array, even though `mergedIntervals` is nowhere mentioned in the `if` block, it indirectly *does* get mutated, because `currentInterval` is its member.

Let's illustrate this with a simple run of this algorithm.

Input: `[[1, 5], [3, 7]]`

Just before the loop starts we have this situation:

```
mergedIntervals
┌─────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ index:  │         0             │
├─────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ content:│ currentInterval       │
│         │ ┌─────────┬───┬───┐   │
│         │ │ index:  │ 0 │ 1 │   │
│         │ ├─────────┼───┼───┤   │
│         │ │ content:│ 1 │ 5 │   │
│         │ └─────────┴───┴───┘   │
└─────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

This visualisation shows the outer array with one slot (index 0), whose content is an inner array with two slots (indices 0 and 1). The key here, is that the variable `currentInterval` references an array that is sitting inside `mergedIntervals`.

Now, when the loop makes its first iteration, it really is a useless iteration, because it lets `nextInterval` be the *first* interval from the input intervals, which is the *same* interval as `currentInterval`. The `if` condition is true, but that `Math.max` expression will be the same value that `currentInterval[1]` already has: 5. So it is a useless iteration, but it doesn't do any harm either.

The second iteration is the interesting one. Here `nextInterval` is the second interval in the input: `[3, 7]`. The `if` condition is true (because 5 >= 3), and so `currentInterval[1]` gets the value of `nextInterval[1]`, which is 7. This effectively extends the current interval, and we get this:

```
mergedIntervals
┌─────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ index:  │         0             │
├─────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ content:│ currentInterval       │
│         │ ┌─────────┬───┬───┐   │
│         │ │ index:  │ 0 │ 1 │   │
│         │ ├─────────┼───┼───┤   │
│         │ │ content:│ 1 │ 7 │   │
│         │ └─────────┴───┴───┘   │
└─────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Note how this affects the result array!

If the second interval would have been smaller such that it would fall completely inside `currentInterval` (e.g. `[3, 4]`), nothing would change, as then the `Math.max` expression would select `currentInterval[1]`. That would indeed be the right thing to do.

In this simple example the loop ends, and the output is indeed what we would expect to get.

I hope this clarifies the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for that thorough explanation! I honestly thought that once we initialize a value with a variable in another array that it kind of gets its own 'namespace' so to say. Would you perhaps have a resource that explains how these pointers work?

Comment: A variable represents its own reference (to an object or array), but if that reference is also present in another object property (or array index), which you can access via a variable, then any *mutation* of the referenced object will be visible via both variables. This is a principle that is at the foundation of what objects and variables are in JavaScript. See also [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605640/5459839)